# ruby - evalulate code returned from another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

ruby 2 and rails 4

Consider this chunk of code:

```
Post.where{
  (created_by == user) & 
  (
    (group_id.in [1,2,3,4]) | (event_id.in [5,6,7,8])
  )
}
```

Which works fine on its own.

What I would like to do is take `(group_id.in [1,2,3,4]) | (event_id.in [5,6,7,8])` and have this come from a local variable, or method, or block or something.

I have many queries and would like this bit of code contained in a single spot.

I have tried several things, like using a block with yield, Proc and lambas. I seem to keep getting stuck on: `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'group_id')`

Note: I am using squeel, which contains its own DSL which uses `instance_eval` for its blocks. Which should be fine because I can access via `my{<method_name_here>}`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
viewable_areas = lambda { (group_id.in [1,2,3,4]) | (event_id.in [5,6,7,8]) }

Post.where{
  (created_by == user) & 
  (
    my{viewable_areas.call}
  )
}
```

The best I can get is the: `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'group_id')`

I know there must be a way of handling this, its just not coming to mind right now.

Also the real code I am working with is much more complex than what I am describing here but I have simplified it for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a named scope:

```
class Post << ...

  scope :viewable_areas, lambda {|group_ids, event_ids| where{(group_id.in group_ids) | (event_id.in event_ids)}

end

Post.viewable_areas([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]).where{created_by == user}
```

concatenation of where calls acts like &

Comment: I was thinking about using scopes, but the parameters for groups and events are dynamic and need to be calculated at run time. Can this be done with scopes? Something like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10949154